# How to solve the antiderivative of $x\cos\left(x^3\right)$

Tags: integration, derivatives

What is the way to solve:

$$\int x\cos\left(x^3\right)\space\text{d}x$$

Thanks, I've no idea how to start

Comment: HINT: use Maclaurin Series

Comment: Is your question posted correctly? If so, the answers below are correct - there is no closed form, only a series solution. But if the integrand is $x \cos x^2$, there is an easy substitution and a closed form.

Comment: I doubt the OP was asking for a closed form solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Maclaurin series of a function:
>
> - $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!}$$
>
> Notice, the Maclaurin series of $\cos(x)$:
>
> - $$\cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
>
> So, we can find the sum when $x^3$:
>
> - $$\cos\left(x^3\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\left(x^3\right)^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{6n}}{(2n)!}$$
>
> Now, we can find the sum when we multiply both sides by $x$:
>
> - $$x\cos\left(x^3\right)=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{6n}}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{6n+1}}{(2n)!}$$

---

Now, we can find the integral, using $\int s^b\space\text{d}s=\frac{s^{b+1}}{b+1}+\text{C}$:

$$\int x\cos\left(x^3\right)\space\text{d}x=\int\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{6n+1}}{(2n)!}\space\text{d}x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\int x^{6n+1}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\cdot\frac{x^{6n+2}}{6n+2}+\text{C}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{6n+2}}{(6n+2)(2n)!}+\text{C}$$

Comment: Isn't that kind of complex (I am not critcizing your answer)? Couldn't you use the regular method (see my answer)?

Answer (score 1):

$\quad\displaystyle\int x\cos(x^3)\mathrm dx$

$=\displaystyle\int x\sum_{k\mathop=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(x^3)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\mathrm dx$

$=\displaystyle\int\left(\sum_{k\mathop=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kx^{6k+1}}{(2k)!}\right)\mathrm dx$

$=\displaystyle\sum_{k\mathop=0}^\infty\int\frac{(-1)^kx^{6k+1}}{(2k)!}\mathrm dx$

$=\displaystyle\sum_{k\mathop=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kx^{6k+2}}{(2k)!(6k+2)}+C$

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your final step.

Answer (score 1):

You can first write $\cos(x^3)$ using exponentials and apply linearity: $$\int \frac{x\left(e^{ix^3} + \frac{1}{e^{ix^3}}\right)}{2} dx = \frac 12 \left(\int x\left(e^{ix^3} + \frac{1}{e^{ix^3}}\right) dx\right)$$

### Solvivng the Integral

First, we need to cancel and/or combine common factors (in case here, we have $e^{ix^3}$): $$\int \left(\frac{x\left(e^{2ix^3} + 1\right)}{e^{ix^3}} dx\right)$$ Then, we can expand the integral and apply linearity: $$\int xe^{ix^3} + \frac{x}{e^{ix^3}} dx = \left(\int xe^{ix^3} dx\right) + \left(\int \frac{x}{e^{ix^3}} dx\right)$$

#### Solving Part I

To solve the first integral, we can substitute $-x^2 \to u$, which means that $\frac{du}{dx} = -2x$: $$-\frac 12\left(\int \frac{1}{e^{u^{1/2}}} du\right)$$ The integral simplifies to: $$-\frac{2\Gamma(\frac 23, u^{3/2})}{3}$$ When we multiply that by $\frac 12$, we get: $$\frac{\Gamma(\frac 23, u^{3/2})}{3}$$ We can undo the substitution and get: $$\frac{\Gamma(\frac 23, -ix^3)}{3}$$

#### Solving Part II

We apply the same method we did in part I, and we will get the same answer as before EXCEPT that the second parameter in the gamma function is actually $\lvert -ix^3 \rvert$.

#### Final Part

When we plug in the integrals, we get: $$\frac{\Gamma(\frac 23, ix^3)}{3} + \frac{\Gamma(\frac 23, -ix^3)}{3}$$ Then, we multiply both addends by $\frac 12$ to get: $$\frac{\Gamma(\frac 23, ix^3)}{6} + \frac{\Gamma(\frac 23, -ix^3)}{6}$$ We finally simplify that to: $$\frac{\Gamma(\frac 23, ix^3) + \Gamma(\frac 23, -ix^3)}{6}$$

So, that is your final answer.